# Value of the node after applying free() on it?

Tags: c, free, output

I was trying to write a simple function to free the memory allocated dynamically

```
typedef struct list{
   int data;
   struct list * link;
} list;

list * head = NULL;
void release(list * head_new){
   list * dummy = NULL;
   while(head_new != NULL){
     dummy = head_new->link;
     printf("before freeing %p, %d", head_new->link, head_new->data);
     free(head_new);
     printf("free returns %p, %d", head_new->link, head_new->data);
     head_new = dummy
   }  
}
```

using a main function values are given to the list and in this particular function even after freeing the head_new node, some values are printed

```
1
12
1
123
1 12 1 123 before freeing 00622A40, 1
free returns 006200C4, 6433408
before freeing 00622A60, 12
free returns 006200C4, 6434048
before freeing 00622A70, 1
free returns 006200C4, 6433344
before freeing 00000000, 123
free returns 00000000, 123
```

if you notice.. the last two lines returns the same value of the data..
even i tried this with bigger list. The same thing happens! last 2,3 values(ie. head_new->data) are returned as it is. 
    My question: Is this a kind of bug? or it's normal to have such values?
    This thing concerns me since there is no return type of free, then how it can show the      same value?
    Please help me clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 6):

```
free(head_new);
printf("free returns %p, %d", head_new->link, head_new->data);
```

Causes your program to have **Undefined behavior(UB)**.
Note that once you called `free` the pointer any attempt to dereference the pointer `head_new` causes an Undefined behavior.
An UB means your program can show any behavior, it does not have to produce a crash. SImply said dereferencing it is Invalid and should not be done.

> **What possibly happens behind the scenes?**

`free` does not reinitialize the deallocated memory it merely marks it free for reusage.
So the contents at the address are still the same and derferencing the pointer gives you those contents. However, it does not matter because UB happened the moment you dereferenced the pointer.

Comment: thank you for your answers :)
can u please clarify one more thing?
In the very next line i have used head_new = dummy meaning that head_new will now point to the same location as dummy does. how this works?
does free makes head_new equal to null? to be more clear i want to ask you what this free function does wid head_new? will this variable be made equal to null? will it be deleted? or will it just contain some garbage value?
since free function is returning back the memomry it had taken from the heap, how can head_new still points to a memomry location?

Comment: @Hemant: free does not make `head_new` `NULL`. `free` simply tells the runtime to treat the memory location as unallocated and free for usage. Nothing more than that.

Comment: then wat happends to head_new?! so does it become a dangling pointer?
I am sorry.. I think i am not clear in my pointers concepts :(

Comment: @Hemant: It is not pointing to anything valid. So it is simply an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The value will be there until it is override by some other data.

The only thing happening when you do free is that the memory will be put back to the free pool so that if other one asks that one will be given.

Comment: oh.. but why is that first 2-3 values change, while these dont?
and after freeing head_new, where will it point?
can you justify its validationin the very next statement?
    head_new = dummy;